# How to resolve undefined response from UPI sdk?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, upi

I am creating a sample project to get payment through a user and I successfully transfer it using pockets but the reponse I recieve is undefined.

txnId=undefined&responseCode=undefined&Status=undefined&txnRef=undefined

My prepared url is: upi://pay?pn=john&tr=598&am=1&cu=INR&pa=9469731359@upi

using this sample code

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            builder.appendQueryParameter("pa" , "9469731359@upi")
                    .appendQueryParameter("pn", "john")         //payee name.
                    .appendQueryParameter("tr", "5983") //transaction reference id.
//                    .appendQueryParameter("mc", "0000")                                 //payee merchant code.
//                    .appendQueryParameter("tn", "transferring1rs")             //transaction description.
                    .appendQueryParameter("am", "1")                                 //amountPayable (hardcoded to make payment of Rupee 1)
                    .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR");                                 //currency code.
            String upiQueryString = "upi://pay" + builder.build().toString();     // virtual payment address of the payee.
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(upiQueryString));
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose respective UPI");                             //Shows a list of UPI enabled PSP apps if more than one is available.
            startActivityForResult(chooser, 1, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        try {
            if (intent != null) {
                String pspResonse = intent.getStringExtra("response");
                String[] pspResonseArray = pspResonse.split("&");
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                for (String param : pspResonseArray) {
                    String key = param.split("=")[0];
                    String value = param.split("=")[1];
                    map.put(key, value);
                }

                TextView txnStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
                TextView txnId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
                TextView txnRef = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
                TextView amount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText13);

                // hide layout 1
                RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
                RelativeLayout layout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);

                layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                txnStatus.setText(map.get("Status"));
                txnId.setText(map.get("txnId"));
                txnRef.setText(map.get("txnRef"));
                amount.setText("1");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Null intent received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

please help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

Hiii, first of all you are using UPI intent call, not upi sdk integration

Following code might help you

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                  .scheme("upi")
                  .authority("pay")
                  .appendQueryParameter("pa", payeeVpaAddress)
                  .appendQueryParameter("pn", payeeName)
                  .appendQueryParameter("tr", transactionRefId)
                  .appendQueryParameter("tn", description)
                  .appendQueryParameter("am", amount should be with fixed to 00, ex. 10.00)
                  .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                  .build();
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pay with...");
startActivityForResult(chooser, <<requestCode>>, null);
```

Add below code in onActivityResult, and check first for which request following result is, that you can check using requestCode

```
if (requestCode == <<requestCode>>) {
  if (data != null) {
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    String response = bundle.getString("response");
    String responseValues[] = getKeyValueFromString(response, "&");
    HashMap<String, String> keyValueOfResponse = new HashMap<>();
    for(String responseValue: responseValues) {
        String []keyValue = getKeyValueFromString(responseValue, "=");
        if(keyValue!= null && keyValue.length > 1) {
            keyValueOfResponse.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
        }
    }
    String txnRef = keyValueOfResponse.get("txnRef");
    String responseCode = keyValueOfResponse.get("responseCode");
    String Status = keyValueOfResponse.get("Status");
    String txnId = keyValueOfResponse.get("txnId");
  }
}
```

Following is just helper function

```
private String[] getKeyValueFromString(String stringToSplit, String splitBy) {
  if (stringToSplit == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return stringToSplit.split(splitBy);
}
```